# How to allow special character in username?

Tags: 7, users

Is there any way to allow the special character in username like "#" and "~"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to override the defualt [user_validate_name($name)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_validate_name/7) :

```
Verify the syntax of the given name.
```

To do that, define your username validation code in your custom module

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {      
    $form['#validate'] = array();
    $form['#validate'][] = 'registration_username_validate';

  }
}
```

And inside registration_username_validate function do your logic to allow your special characters.

Care about **security issues** caused by allowing special chars in username and about display issues not sanitized usernames may cause in themes.

Comment: Note, `$form['#validate'] = array();` will clobber any existing validate handlers, including potentially those set by other contrib/custom modules. Better to selectively unset overridden validate function.

Comment: @rock thanx. I checked the old database i have only two users so I will notify user of change their username. Thanks btw your solution is good. ;)

Comment: Also worth noting that this method is far preferable to hacking the Drupal core function inside user.module

Comment: It's also possible to use function MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter()

Comment: **This answer is dangerous.** As [David Thomas mentioned](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73668/how-to-allow-special-character-in-username/183945#comment81133_73670) this will replace any other validators, including the default `user_account_form_validate` function which validates more than just the username. **Replacing this could allow duplicate usernames!**

I've added [an answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73668/how-to-allow-special-character-in-username/183945#183945) that gets around these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward way to do this. By default `user_register_form` and `user_profile_form` have [`user_account_form_validate`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form_validate/7) set as their first validator in `$form['#validate']`. `user_account_form_validate()` checks and cleans up the name, email, and signature of an account. As part of checking the name it makes a call to [`user_validate_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_validate_name/7). This is the function we want to override, not `user_account_form_validate`.

One would hope for a helpful hook to override it, but alas. If I didn't care 
about validation of the email and signature as well the check to see if the 
name is a duplicate, I could just remove `user_account_form_validate` from 
`$form['#validate']`. But that's no good. Instead, I add an additional 
validator that undoes the work of `user_validate_name()` and redoes everything
without the special character check.

```
<?php
function MODULENAME_form_user_register_form_alter(
  array &$form, array &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  MODULENAME_add_name_validator($form);
}

function MODULENAME_form_user_profile_form_alter(
  array &$form, array &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  MODULENAME_add_name_validator($form);
}

function MODULENAME_add_name_validator(array &$form)
{
  $validate =& $form['#validate'];
  # Since `validate_name()` clears out any errors for the "name" field, we
  # want to put it right after the validator we want to partially override.
  $acct_validate_index = array_search('user_account_form_validate', $validate);
  array_splice($validate, ($acct_validate_index + 1), 0,
    ['MODULENAME_validate_name']
  );
}

function MODULENAME_validate_name(array $form, array &$form_state)
{
  # There is no blessed way of overriding the call to `user_validate_name()` in
  # `user_account_form_validate()`.
  $errors =& drupal_static('form_set_error', []);
    # Yes, this gets the errors. `form_get_error()` uses this method so... yeah.
  if (!isset($errors['name']))
    # `user_validate_name()` is a superset of what is checked here. If the name
    # passed that validation, no need to rerun things.
    return;

  # `form_set_error()` also calls `drupal_set_message()` if it finds an
  # error.
  $msg_index = array_search($errors['name'], $_SESSION['messages']['error']);
  if ($msg_index !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION['messages']['error'][$msg_index]);
    if (empty($_SESSION['messages']['error']))
      unset($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
  }
  unset($errors['name']);

  $name = isset($form_state['values']['name'])
          ? $form_state['values']['name'] : null;

  # These checks are taken from `user_validate_name()`, simply excluding the
  # for characters we don't mind being in the names.
  if (!$name)
    $error = t('You must enter a username.');
  else if (substr($name, 0, 1) == ' ')
    $error = t('The username cannot begin with a space.');
  else if (substr($name, -1) == ' ')
    $error = t('The username cannot end with a space.');
  else if (strpos($name, '  ') !== FALSE)
    $error = t('The username cannot contain multiple spaces in a row.');
  else if (preg_match('/[\x{80}-\x{A0}' .   // Non-printable ISO-8859-1 + NBSP
                      '\x{AD}' .            // Soft-hyphen
                      '\x{2000}-\x{200F}' . // Various space characters
                      '\x{2028}-\x{202F}' . // Bidirectional text overrides
                      '\x{205F}-\x{206F}' . // Various text hinting characters
                      '\x{FEFF}' .          // Byte order mark
                      '\x{FF01}-\x{FF60}' . // Full-width latin
                      '\x{FFF9}-\x{FFFD}' . // Replacement characters
                      '\x{0}-\x{1F}]/u',    // NULL byte and control characters
                      $name))
    $error = t('The username contains an illegal character.');
  else if (drupal_strlen($name) > USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH)
    $error = t('The username %name is too long: it must be %max characters '
              .'or less.'
              ,['%name' => $name, '%max' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH]);

  if (isset($error))
    form_set_error('name', $error);
}
```

There is still a special character check, however it only checks for 
invisible or special use characters.